# Does empty "else" cost any time

Tags: c++

Is there any difference in computational cost of

```
if(something){
    return something;
}else{
    return somethingElse;
}
```

and

```
if(something){
    return something;
}
//else (put in comments for readibility purposes)
return somethingElse;
```

In theory we have command (else) but it doesn't seem it should make an actuall difference.

Edit:
After running code for different set sizes, I found that there actually is a differrence, code without else appears to be about 1.5% more efficient. But it most likely depends on compiler, as stated by many people below. Code I tested it on:

```
int withoutElse(bool a){
if(a)
    return 0;
return 1;

}


int withElse(bool a){
if(a)
    return 0;
else
    return 1;
}


int main(){
using namespace std;
bool a=true;
clock_t begin,end;
begin= clock();
for(__int64 i=0;i<1000000000;i++){
    a=!a;
    withElse(a);
}
end = clock();
cout<<end-begin<<endl;

begin= clock();
for(__int64 i=0;i<1000000000;i++){
    a=!a;
    withoutElse(a);
}
end = clock();
cout<<end-begin<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Checked on loops from 1 000 000 to 1 000 000 000, and results were consistently different

Edit 2:
Assembly code (once again, generated using Visual Studio 2010) also shows small difference (appareantly, I'm no good with assemblers :()

```
   ?withElse@@YAH_N@Z PROC                  ; withElse, COMDAT
   ; Line 12
push    ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp, 192                ; 000000c0H
push    ebx
push    esi
push    edi
lea edi, DWORD PTR [ebp-192]
mov ecx, 48                 ; 00000030H
mov eax, -858993460             ; ccccccccH
rep stosd
   ; Line 13
movzx   eax, BYTE PTR _a$[ebp]
test    eax, eax
je  SHORT $LN2@withElse
   ; Line 14
xor eax, eax
jmp SHORT $LN3@withElse
   ; Line 15
jmp SHORT $LN3@withElse
   $LN2@withElse:
   ; Line 16
mov eax, 1
   $LN3@withElse:
   ; Line 17
pop edi
pop esi
pop ebx
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
ret 0
   ?withElse@@YAH_N@Z ENDP                  ; withElse
```

and

```
   ?withoutElse@@YAH_N@Z PROC               ; withoutElse, COMDAT
   ; Line 4
push    ebp
mov ebp, esp
sub esp, 192                ; 000000c0H
push    ebx
push    esi
push    edi
lea edi, DWORD PTR [ebp-192]
mov ecx, 48                 ; 00000030H
mov eax, -858993460             ; ccccccccH
rep stosd
   ; Line 5
movzx   eax, BYTE PTR _a$[ebp]
test    eax, eax
je  SHORT $LN1@withoutEls
   ; Line 6
xor eax, eax
jmp SHORT $LN2@withoutEls
   $LN1@withoutEls:
   ; Line 7
mov eax, 1
   $LN2@withoutEls:
   ; Line 9
pop edi
pop esi
pop ebx
mov esp, ebp
pop ebp
ret 0
   ?withoutElse@@YAH_N@Z ENDP               ; withoutElse
```

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: Check the generated assembler code for both variants. That's the only way to be sure.

Comment: not exactly a complexity theory question.

Comment: As far as I know an else doesn't even cost run time, does it?

Comment: @devnull I know, but while writing code it made me curious if there is any difference.

Comment: @devnull: But premature pessimisation is worse. There's no reason not to learn which code constructs can be more efficient than others, even if (to continue your partial quotation) "we should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time".

Comment: _"In theory we have command (else)"_ No, we don't, we have a language construct. Anyways: compilers aren't as dumb as you may think. They have free reign to ignore some of your code, like `register int i;` might not be stored in the register at all

Comment: @Xyzk Can you repeat your measurements with a Release build? The time difference could be caused by the compiler allowing the debugger to break inside the `else` basic block, which would most likely be optimised out in Release.

Comment: @ComicSansMS I did, and while the code changed, versions are still slightly different

Comment: jmp SHORT $LN3@withElse ; Line 15 jmp SHORT $LN3@withElse << only for code alignment, the first instruction will never allow the second.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is generically different, but the compiler may decide to execute the same jump in both cases **(it will practically do this always**).
The best way to see what a compiler does is reading the assembler. Assuming that you are using gcc you can try with

```
gcc -g -c -fverbose-asm myfile.c; objdump -d -M intel -S myfile.o > myfile.s
```

which creates a mix of assembler/c code and makes the job easier at the beginning.

As for your example it is:

**CASE1**

```
if(something){
23: 83 7d fc 00             cmp    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],0x0
27: 74 05                   je     2e <main+0x19>
    return something;
29: 8b 45 fc                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4]
2c: eb 05                   jmp    33 <main+0x1e>
}else{
    return 0;
2e: b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
}
```

**CASE2**

```
if(something){
23: 83 7d fc 00             cmp    DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4],0x0
27: 74 05                   je     2e <main+0x19>
    return something;
29: 8b 45 fc                mov    eax,DWORD PTR [ebp-0x4]
2c: eb 05                   jmp    33 <main+0x1e>
return 0;
2e: b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
```

As you could imagine there are ***no differences***!

Comment: Let's stress again that this is the code that one specific compiler generated in a debug build without optimizations. You might get vastly different results on other compilers or compiler options. The bottom line however still applies: The difference is unlikely to be big enough to be of any concern.

Comment: Your answer was most helpfull but as I note in my edit, in MVS there actually is a small difference

Comment: It's likely that that difference would go away if you enabled optimizations.

Answer (score 2):

It won't compile if you type `return 
Think that once the code gets compiled, all ifs, elses and loops are changed to goto's

```
If (cond) { code A } code B
```

turns to

```
if cond is false jump to code b
code A
code B
```

and 
    If (cond) { code A } else { code B } code C

turns to

```
if cond is false jump to code B
code A
ALWAYS jump to code C
code B

code C
```

Most processors 'guess' whether they're going to jump or not before checking if they actually jump. Depending on the processor, it might affect the performance to fail a guess.

So the answer is YES! (unless there's an ALWAYS jump at the end of first comparison) It will take 2-3 cycles to do the ALWAYS jump which isn't in the first if.

Comment: But that's the question, does it add another goto, similarly to if-else(condition), or does compiler actually treat it like speciall case